# Compress Image before Saving to disk in Java

Tags: java, image, compression

Is it possible to compress an image before saving it?
I'm using the Robot class to capture images, and it returns a BufferedImage.
How can I compress this image and then save it?

Comment: Images are generally compressed pretty well anyway if you store them in JPG or PNG format.  The advantage being they are ready to use from a multitude of applications.

Answer (score 3):

`.png` files are (losslessly) compressed images.

You can use [ImageIO.write()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#write%28java.awt.image.RenderedImage,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.OutputStream%29) to [save a .png image](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html):

```
ImageIO.write(myBufferedImage, "png", outputfile);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is colour compression ("compression quality") and there is resolution compression ("resizing").  E.g. I got a 4mb photo to 270K using a very low "compression quality", but that looked awful, but I got it down to 12K using a reasonable quality but a smaller size.

My recommendation for resizing:

https://github.com/rkalla/imgscalr/blob/master/src/main/java/org/imgscalr/Scalr.java

I wish resizing was part of the standard Java libraries, but it seems it's not, (or there are image quality problems with the standard methods?). But Riyad's library is really small - it's just one class. I just copied this class into my project, because I never learnt how to use Maven, and it works great.
[How can I compress images using java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44565500/how-can-i-compress-images-using-java)

My recommendation for compression quality:   See fujy's answer in:

[How can I compress images using java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44565500/how-can-i-compress-images-using-java)