# How can I compress images using java?

Tags: java, image, image-processing, image-compression, google-pagespeed

From pagespeed I am getting only image link and possible optimizations in bytes & percentage like,
 Compressing and resizing [https://example.com/…ts/xyz.jpg?036861](https://example.com/%E2%80%A6ts/xyz.jpg?036861) could save 212KiB (51% reduction).
 Compressing [https://example.com/…xyz.png?303584508](https://example.com/%E2%80%A6xyz.png?303584508) could save 4.4KiB (21% reduction).

For an example I have image of size 300kb and for this image pagespeed is displaying 100kb & 30% of reduction.

This is only for one image but I am sure I will have lots of images for compression.
 so how can I compress image by passing bytes or percentage as a parameter or using anyother calculations in java
 (by using API or image-processing Tool) so,that I can get compressed version of image as suggested by google.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 39):

You can use Java [`ImageIO`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/package-summary.html) package to do the compression for many images formats, here is an example

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Iterator;
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.imageio.stream.*;

public class Compresssion {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    File input = new File("original_image.jpg");
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(input);

    File compressedImageFile = new File("compressed_image.jpg");
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(compressedImageFile);

    Iterator<ImageWriter> writers = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpg");
    ImageWriter writer = (ImageWriter) writers.next();

    ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(os);
    writer.setOutput(ios);

    ImageWriteParam param = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();

    param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
    param.setCompressionQuality(0.05f);  // Change the quality value you prefer
    writer.write(null, new IIOImage(image, null, null), param);

    os.close();
    ios.close();
    writer.dispose();
  }
}
```

You can find more details about it [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_dip/image_compression_technique.htm)

Also there are some third party tools like these

- https://collicalex.github.io/JPEGOptimizer/
- https://github.com/depsypher/pngtastic

**EDIT:** If you want to use Google `PageSpeed` in your application, it is available as web server module either for Apache or Nginx, you can find how to configure it for your website here

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/

But if you want to integrate the `PageSpeed` C++ library in your application, you can find build instructions for it here.

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/psol

It also has a Java Client here

https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client-services/tree/main/clients/google-api-services-pagespeedonline/v5

Comment: Using ImageWriteParam I got the compressed version of images but  I am not getting required compression whatever google page speed is suggesting.

so, basically I want compressed version of image whatever google page speed is suggesting .

Comment: A lot of interesting information on this answer. Thanks :)

Comment: What about resizing?  Resizing is the main way to reduce file size.

Comment: This works with jpg/jpeg images as written. If image is a png image the following code throws exception even if you use get image writer for png

Answer (score 10):

There is colour compression ("compression quality") and there is resolution compression ("resizing").  Fujy's answer deals with compression quality, but this is not where the main savings come from:  the main savings come from resizing down to a smaller size.  E.g. I got a 4mb photo to 207K using the maximum compression quality using fujy's answer, and it looked awful, but I got it down to 12K using a reasonable quality but a smaller size.

So the above code should be used for "compression quality", but this is my recommendation for resizing:

https://github.com/rkalla/imgscalr/blob/master/src/main/java/org/imgscalr/Scalr.java

I wish resizing was part of the standard Java libraries, but it seems it's not, (or there are image quality problems with the standard methods?).  But Riyad's library is really small - it's just one class.  I just copied this class into my project, because I never learnt how to use Maven, and it works great.

Comment: The code you given is hard to understand, can you give another code please...

Comment: @Johndahat Copy paste Scalr class from URL above. Then, you may use it, such as `BufferedImage img = Scalr.resize(ImageIO.read(src), 500);` where `src` is a `File`, `URL` or `InputStream`.

Answer (score 3):

One liner java solution: thumbnailator.

Maven dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.coobird/thumbnailator -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.coobird</groupId>
    <artifactId>thumbnailator</artifactId>
    <version>0.4.17</version>
</dependency>
```

The one liner:

```
Thumbnails.of(inputImagePathString).scale(scalingFactorFloat).outputQuality(qualityFactorFloat).toFile(outputImagePathString);
```

Answer (score 2):

As a solution for this problem I can recommend the API of TinyPNG.
You can use it for compressing as well as resizing the image.

**Documentation:** *[tinypng.com/developers/reference/java](https://tinypng.com/developers/reference/java)*

Comment: unfortunately it has web API only which brings some network delay to processing. Do they have any client library which does the compression clientside without the need  of API?