# Compress JPEG to 100kb

Tags: java

What is the general approach to compress an image to JPEG with a target 100kb size?
Either lowering the "*bitrate*", automatically resizing the image, both?

That is, using pure Java and no external "native" dependencies.

Comment: https://github.com/coobird/thumbnailator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to use: https://github.com/fewlaps/slim-jpg

```java
Result result = SlimJpg.file(imageBytes)
                .maxVisualDiff(0.5)
                .maxFileWeightInKB(100)
                .deleteMetadata()
                .optimize();
byte[] compressedBytes = result.getPicture();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Java `ImageIO` package to do the compression using **pure** Java. You have the documentaion here: [javax.imageio](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/package-summary.html)

Here is an example how to use it, the example is from this thread if you want to read more about it: [How can I compress images using java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44565500/how-can-i-compress-images-using-java)

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Iterator;
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.imageio.stream.*;

public class Compresssion {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    File input = new File("original_image.jpg");
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(input);

    File compressedImageFile = new File("compressed_image.jpg");
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(compressedImageFile);

    Iterator<ImageWriter> writers = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpg");
    ImageWriter writer = (ImageWriter) writers.next();

    ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(os);
    writer.setOutput(ios);

    ImageWriteParam param = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();

    param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
    param.setCompressionQuality(0.05f);  // Change the quality value you prefer
    writer.write(null, new IIOImage(image, null, null), param);

    os.close();
    ios.close();
    writer.dispose();
  }
}
```